# Как можно сократить очень много elif с помощью списков?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, list, aiogram

Не могу догнать как сократить код. Пытаюсь сделать бота для группового чата в тг, использую библиотеку `aiogram`. Хендлер ниже, распознает ключевое слово в сообщении что отправляет юзер, и отвечает определенным войсом. Я сделал это при помощи условий, но в таком случае очень много `elif`, что то мне подсказывает что это можно упростить при помощи списков, но я не могу догнать как.

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_user_text(message):
    Value = -1
    if message.text.find('Привет') != Value or message.text.find('привет') != Value:
        hallo = open('voice/audio_2022-10-27_12-46-18.ogg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, hallo)
    elif message.text.find('пока') != Value or message.text.find('Пока') != Value:
        bay = open('voice/audio_2022-10-27_RJ13-05-33.ogg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, bay)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь коллекцией, например, списком кортежей. Кроме того, если вам не нужна позиция искомого слова, то искать лучше через `in`, а не через `.find`, ну и если привести искомые слова и текст к одному регистру, то можно искать одно слово, а не два варианта написания одного слова.

```
text2voice = [
('привет', 'voice/audio_2022-10-27_12-46-18.ogg'),
('пока',   'voice/audio_2022-10-27_RJ13-05-33.ogg'),
...
]

@dp.message_handler()
async def get_user_text(message):
    for word, filename in text2voice:
        if word in message.text.lower():
            voice = open(filename, 'rb')
            await bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, voice)
```